# React Hooks. Updating parent state from multiple children at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, async-await

### Description of my current situation:

I am developing an app to sell books, and I am using React Context to share the state between screens. When I enter a book screen, I have two buttons (custom childs components) "add to cart" and "save",  that when mount, they fetch their respective initial state (added to cart or saved, respectively) on my DB.

### Problem

When the button "add to cart" finishes getting its initial state from the DB, it updates its parent state
"currentBookData" via a callback which receives as prop.

The same for the other button.

Here is the code for my book screen:

```
  function BookScreen(props) { // 
       const [bookData, setBookData] = useState(props.params.selectedBookData);


       const handleButtonAddToCartLoad = (isAddedToCart) => {
            const {currentUser} = props; // provided by the context

           // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
           const newBookData = { ...bookData, isAddedToCart };
           setBookData(newBookData);

           currentUser.addVisitedBook(newBookData.id, newBookData); // Update the book in the map of visited books
       }


       const handleButtonSaveLoad = (isSaved) => {
           const {currentUser} = props; // provided by the context

           // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
           const newBookData = { ...bookData, isSaved };
           setBookData(newBookData);

           currentUser.addVisitedBook(newBookData.id, newBookData); // Update the book in the map of visited books
       }
        


       useEffect(() => {
            // When the screen mounts, update the book data if it wasn't fetched previously
            (async () => {
                const {currentUser} = props; // provided by the context

                if(!currentUser.getVisitedBook(bookData.id)) {

                   // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                   const newBookData = await db.getBook(bookData.id); 

                   // Add the book to the visited books of list
                   currentUser.addVisitedBook(newBookData.id, newBookData );
                }
            })();
       }, []);


       return (
             <View>
                ...
                <AddToCartButton bookId={bookData.id} onLoad={handleButtonAddToCartLoad } />
                <SaveButton bookId={bookData.id} onLoad={handleButtonSaveLoad} />
             </View>
       )

         
  }

  export default withCurrentUser(BookScreen); // <------ It consumes the context where I have a Map with all the data which has been downloaded from the DB. Just to avoid unnecessary requests.
```

As you can imagine after reading the code, I am updating state using the normal standard hook provided by React. What happens is that the updates comes at the same time, so state is not "merged", it always is the one from the last update:

```
    {
        id: "bookId",
        title: "bookTitle",
        isAddedToCart: false,
    }
```

or

```
    {
        id: "bookId",
        title: "bookTitle",
        isSaved: true,
    }
```

or sometimes

```
   {
        id: "bookId",
        title: "bookTitle",
    }
```

but never what I need it to be

```
    {
        id: "bookId",
        title: "bookTitle",
        isAddedToCart: false,
        isSaved: true,
    }
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem using hooks??

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: And is possible to do something like this?  let _prevData; setData(prevData => { _prevData = prevData;  return prevData;  } just to move it out from the local scope?

Comment: No, the callback is invoked asynchronously. Just do the aggregation inside the callback and return the new state from within the callback.

Comment: Man, one last question. Will this be the same to use this custom hook? https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-get-previous-props-state-with-react-hooks/  Or is the one you show me the only way to access the previous state when updating it?

Comment: _In my opinion_, using that custom hook to get the previous state is a bit of a code smell. You'd be able to use it, yes, but code that depends on it will tend to be messy in my experience. If you want to avoid passing a callback to `setData()` and the way you merge the new data with the previous data is always the same, then you can change your `useState()` to [`useReducer()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) instead.